# How to know if easyTimer is stopped or not?

Tags: javascript

How do I validate to see if the counter is counting? or if it is stopped?
i'm using easyTimer js...I took an example

```
#example
if(basicUsage.Stop == True){
alert("stopped");
}


<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/easytimer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var timer = new easytimer.Timer();

    timer.start();

    timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
        $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
    });
</script>

<div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example based on your code

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/easytimer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var timer = new easytimer.Timer();

        timer.start();

        timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
            $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
        });

        $("#btnStop").click(function () {
            timer.stop();
        });

        $("#btnCheck").click(function () {
            if (timer.isRunning() == false) {
                alert("Timer is not running");
            }
            else {
                alert("Timer is running");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="basicUsage">00:00:00</div>

<input type="button" id="btnStop" value="Stop" />
<input type="button" id="btnCheck" value="Check" />
```

Comment: did not answer my question but helped!